Safety Sourdough Banana Bread with Long Fermentation
I like the idea of making a sourdough banana bread that ferments before baking. However, I'm concerned about the safety given than there would be eggs and possibly other dairy in the enriched bread. I see several recipes online but none mention this. I wonder if the solution is to ferment the dough in the fridge so not to expose it to warm temperatures. Or use vegan ingredients.
Has anyone made a naturally leavened, long fermentation banana bread? If so, what was your method to ensure safety?

This is not what you asking for, but I have made a long fermented rustic bread with banana in it where I replace most of the water with banana. So flour, sourdough starter, and banana. So imagine a rustic tartine style bread with banana in it. Ends up being a dense bread with a subtle sweetness and banana flavor. And this recipe included a several hour bulk fermentation followed by a 24 hour retard in the fridge.

You could take inspiration from overnight sourdough pancake recipes. Those involve mixing flour, milk or yogurt, and sourdough starter. Then in the morning you add in the fat and eggs. If you are looking to make more of a battery banana bread this could probably work. I think adding the banana initially will be fine, then incorporate the eggs and fat after fermenting just before baking.

What I ended up doing was mix ripe starter, flour, oil, honey and mashed banana and let it ferment overnight until about a 50% rise (I could've gone further). Then separately beat the eggs and added baking powder and soda, cinnamon and salt (a little hard to incorporate it all into the eggs). Then mixed everything together, gently to not develop gluten. I also added some chopped pecans and chocolate chips (which all sank to the bottom) but the flavor was great and I really liked the texture. Now I want to try it with pumpkin!!

@hodale Cooks Illustrated has a recipe like this for yeasted pancakes that ferments the whole thing overnight in the fridge (with eggs and everything included). OP mentions this, and it would be a valid way of accomplishing this goal.
